# Setting global rotation of a vector using a quaternion in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, geometry, quaternions

I would like to set the absolute global rotation of a vector using a quaternion.

Let's say I have a function `f(v, q)` which rotates vector `v` *to* quaternion `q`.

`THREE.Vector3` has a `.applyQuaternion` function which applies a rotation to a vector, but this is a relative rotation. For example, the function call `f(f(v, q), q)` will apply `q` twice. Instead,  I would expect `f(f(v, q), q) = f(v, q)` since `q` is the absolute rotation of the vector.

I know that I can compute some `deltaQ = currentQ.premultiply(q.inverse())` and then call `.applyQuaternion`, but I don't know how to query the `currentQ`, or the current rotation of the vector, so that I can "undo" it and apply the new quaternion.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I would ideally like to rotate about a point defined in world coordinate space, which is why I have the `object.worldToLocal` and `object.localToWorld` calls. However, the orbiting object flies off the map when I make these conversions.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
/* const orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); */

// CONSTRUCT ORBITER
const orbitGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32);
const orbitMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({colors: 0xff0000});
const orbiter = new THREE.Mesh(orbitGeometry, orbitMaterial);

// CONSTRUCT GLOBAL AXES
const xDir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
const yDir = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
const zDir = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
const origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const xArrowWorld = new THREE.ArrowHelper(xDir, origin, 3, 0xFF00FF);
const yArrowWorld = new THREE.ArrowHelper(yDir, origin, 3, 0xffff00);
const zArrowWorld = new THREE.ArrowHelper(zDir, origin, 3, 0x00b7eb);
const worldAxes = new THREE.Group();
worldAxes.add(xArrowWorld);
worldAxes.add(yArrowWorld);
worldAxes.add(zArrowWorld);


// CONSTRUCT MARKER
const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32);
const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
const marker = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);

// scene.add(axes);
scene.add(marker);
scene.add(orbiter);
scene.add(worldAxes);

camera.position.z = 5;
camera.position.y = 3;
camera.position.x = 3;
camera.lookAt(worldAxes.position);

marker.position.set(1, 0, 0);

function rotateEuler(object, point, eulerX, eulerY, eulerZ, isExtrinsic = false) {
    if (isExtrinsic) {
        object.rotation.order = 'ZYX';
    } else {
        object.rotation.order = 'XYZ';
    }
    const q = new THREE.Quaternion();
    const eul = new THREE.Euler(eulerX, eulerY, eulerZ, object.rotation.order);
    q.setFromEuler(eul);
    rotateQuaternionAroundPoint(object, point, q);
}

function rotateQuaternionAroundPoint(object, point, q) {

    object.rotation.set(0, 0, 0)
    object.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    object.localToWorld(object.position);
    object.position.sub(point);
    object.position.applyQuaternion(q);
    object.position.add(point);
    object.worldToLocal(object.position);

}

let rotY = 0;
let rotationPoint = marker.localToWorld(marker.position.clone());

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    rotY += 0.01;

    rotateEuler(orbiter, rotationPoint, 0, rotY, 0, true);

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to reset the `Vector3` to its initial state, then apply the quaternion to this reset vector. This erases any previous rotation from the equation. For instance, assuming the default state of the vector is pointing `'UP'`:

```
function f(v, q) {
    v.set(0, 1, 0);
    v.applyQuaternion(q);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe this works for the most part. However, once I add the coordinate system transforms to apply this as a global transform, there is some strange behavior. I've updated my post with a fiddle to illustrate.

Comment: @Carpetfizz it looks like changing `object.localToWorld(object.position)` to `object.parent.localToWorld(object.position)` and `object.worldToLocal(object.position)` to `object.parent.worldToLocal(object.position)` fixes this issue.